# Expected number of rounds to reach an intersection size

Tags: probability, combinatorics, set-theory, expected-value

Consider the set $U=\{1,..,n\}$, and $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\emptyset$ are two empty sets to begin. Perform the following step.

Choose $m$ elements from $U$ uniformly at random (with replacement) and add to $A$. Similarly, choose $m$ elements from $U$ uniformly at random (with replacement) and add to $B$.

Given a number $0<v\leq n$, what is the expected number of times one has to repeat the step to get $|A\cap B|\geq v$?

Comment: What happens if after a step $|A\cap B|$ has gone from being less than $v$ to being greater than $v$?

Comment: I edited the question to make it $\geq v$. I believe one can derive the equality case from this.

Comment: I suspect using indicator variables for events like $i\in A$ and $i\in B$ would work well. What work have you done on the problem yourself?

Comment: PS: use $\emptyset$, \emptyset, for the empty set, and not \phi

Comment: @Milten I was thinking, maybe, we can use the Coupon Collector's solution to determine expected rounds to get $i$ distinct members in each of those sets, and then find the expected size of the intersection of two sets with $i$ elements in each. But, I am not sure how to put it all together.